# why does the compiler doesn't give error while assigning long to float?

Tags: java

when i execute the below code, i expected it to get warning "can't convert from long to float" because the float is 32 bits and long is 64 bits in size.
But looks like no warning,
Could anyone explain me how?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    float a=1;
    long b=123;
     a=b;
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Comment: if float cant hold the assigned value, then it'll overflow/underflow

Comment: @MohammadAdil: Well it may not be able to hold the *exact* value (in which case it will round) but it won't overflow/underflow.

Comment: Widening by defition means casting to a type with wider range (though perhaps with less precision) When you widen, it's not possible to underflow or overflow.

Answer (score 5):

The range of `float` is much larger than the range of `long`... there's an implicit conversion which may lose precision, but not magnitude. The same is true for `long` to `double`.

From [JLS 5.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2):

> A widening primitive conversion from `int` to `float`, or from `long` to `float`, or from `long` to `double`, may result in *loss of precision* - that is, the result may lose some of the least significant bits of the value. In this case, the resulting floating-point value will be a correctly rounded version of the integer value, using IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode (§4.2.4).